# Perfect Number Lister

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to get a program that lists out perfect numbers in a certain range.

```
minv= int(input('Give me a minimum value: '))
maxv= int(input('Give me a minimum value: '))
thesum = 0

perfectnums = []

for val in range(minr, maxr + 1):
    for n in range(1, val):
        if val % n == 0:
            thesum += n
            if thesum == val:
                perfectnums.append(val)

print(perfectnums)
```

I expect 6 to pop out when I put min value at 1 and max value at 10

Comment: A perfect number is equal to the sum of its divisors.  You must process all of the divisors, and then test whether their sum is equal to the value.  The `sum == val` test must be done after the loop iterates over the possible divisors. For each `val` that you probe, you must initialize the `sum` to zero; that `thesum = 0` must be moved into the outer loop.

Comment: Also you obviously copy&pasted the input-line. Take a look at your second input prompt!

Answer (score 2):

For each val you should put `thesum = 0`

```
minv= int(input('Give me a minimum value: '))
maxv= int(input('Give me a minimum value: '))
thesum = 0

perfectnums = []

for val in range(minr, maxr + 1):

    # here
    thesum = 0

    for n in range(1, val):
        if val % n == 0:
            thesum += n
            if thesum == val:
                perfectnums.append(val)

print(perfectnums)
```

Answer (score 1):

You never reset `thesum` to 0. Therefore, it carries between numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting `thesum` inside the `for val ...` loop. Otherwise it just grows.
(Also I assume your `minv` vs `minr` and `maxv` vs `maxr` is just a typo. Make sure those are the same.)

Answer (score 0):

In the first **for loop** you should reset the `thesum`variable. Here's the working code:

```
minv= int(input('Give me a minimum value: '))

maxv= int(input('Give me a minimum value: '))

perfectnums = []

for val in range(minv, maxv + 1): # right variables minv and maxv
    thesum = 0 # declare the variable here

    for n in range(1, val):

        if val % n == 0:

            thesum += n

            if thesum == val:

                perfectnums.append(val)


print(perfectnums)
```

Now, for `minv = 1`and `maxv = 10`, You will get `[6]`as result!

Answer (score 0):

Putting together what GaryO and Alex said, and fixing the text within the questions:

```
minv= int(input('Give me a minimum value: '))
maxv= int(input('Give me a maximum value: '))

perfectnums = []

for val in range(minv, maxv + 1):
    thesum = 0
    for n in range(1, val):
        if val % n == 0:
            thesum += n
            if thesum == val:
                perfectnums.append(val)

print(perfectnums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset `thesum` back to `0`:

```
minv= int(input('Give me a minimum value: '))
maxv= int(input('Give me a maximum value: '))
thesum = 0

perfectnums = []

for val in range(minv, maxv + 1):
    for n in range(1, val):
        if val % n == 0:
            thesum += n
    if thesum == val:
        perfectnums.append(val)
    thesum = 0
```